# How I limit characetrs from text area using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text box, whose character dosent exceed 10 characters in angularjs directive.

Here is an HTML option from console,

```
<input type="text" id="segmentName" ng-change="mmModelChange()" class="mm-text-box  ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" style="width: 252px;" ng-class="{disable: $parent.mmDisable, errorInput: $parent.mmError}" ng-show="$parent.isShowControl || (!!$parent.mmError &amp;&amp; $parent.mmError !='' )" ng-model="$parent.$parent.mmModel" mm-focus="$parent.setFocus || ($parent.mmShowAsLabel &amp;&amp; $parent.isShowControl)" ng-blur="mmModelBlur();$parent.$parent.isShowControl = !$parent.$parent.mmShowAsLabel; " ng-disabled="$parent.mmDisable" placeholder="" tabindex="">
```

Comment: Why can't you use `maxlength` or `size`?

Comment: text area or text box? Could you show your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

**Textbox**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" >
```

**Textarea**

```
<textarea  maxlength="10"></textarea>
```

If you wanna to use angular directive then

Try this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-maxlength="10">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `maxlength` attribute:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10">
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but may be this might work?

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
  var maxlength = Number(attrs.myMaxlength);
  function fromUser(text) {
      ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('unique', text.length <= maxlength);
      return text;
  }
  ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
}
```

Or for `<input />`, use:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use maxlength in the html on the text input. Something like `maxlength="10"`.